# AppRTC deployment runtime error

Tags: webrtc, apprtc

I deployed AppRTC on Google Cloud Engine. I had also configured the collider using the go commands. When I Join the call, I get the following error on the second peer:

```
Room server join error: Failed to join the room: Status=500
WebSocket register error: Failed to join the room: Status=500
```

[image]

Anyone ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It says you do not have turn server, so please configure your Turn server and also for getting TURN server information you have to configure your own API

you will have to install TURN server and change the TURN_BASE_URL in src/app_engine/constants.py to point to your own API server which can send back the response something like this

```
app.post('/turn', function (req, res) {
  console.log("Turn server needed");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://apprtc.callstats.io');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    var turn_server = {
    url: 'turn server url',
    username: 'test',
    credential: '1234',
    realm: 'reTurn'
  };


  var turn_server_tls = {
    url: 'turn server url',
    username: 'test',
    credential: '1234',
    realm: 'reTurn'
  };

  var iceServers = [turn_server,turn_server_tls];

  var pc_config = {'iceTransports': 'all','iceServers': iceServers};
  res.json(pc_config)
});
```